# Como hacer funcionar el proxy incluido en el package.json para las llamadas axios

Tags: vue.js, cors, axios

Tengo configurada una aplicación VUE que tiene como backend una aplicacion net.core

Para evitar los problemas de cors, seria ideal configurar un proxy. Sin embargo mis intentos fueron en vano, ya que no encontre la forma de hacerlo.

La aplicacion esta creada con el CLI 3 de vue, y usa typescript.

Probe agregar al archivo package.json las siguientes lineas, pero el proxy sigue sin andar, o sea todas las llamadas se siguen haciendo al servidor saliente:

```
"proxyTable": {
    "/api":{
      "target": "http://localhost:5000",
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      }
    }
  },
```

---

```
"proxy": {
    "/api":"http://localhost:5000"
      }
```

Ninguna de estas cosas me movio la llamada a ese puerto.

Las llamadas son axios como por ejemplo:

```
Axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URI + 'me', { }, {withCredentials: true})
```

donde la constante esta definida como:

```
VUE_APP_BASE_URI=api/
```

La constante se ve y funciona. sin la constante, el error se produce igual.

Es algun problema en como tengo escrito el proxy o estoy cometiendo algun otro error?

mi package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "proxyTable": {
    "/api":{
      "target": "http://localhost:5000",
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/api": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Uno de los intentos fue el recomendado por [esta página](https://www.techiediaries.com/vue-cli-tutorial/#Vue_CLI_Proxy). y lo mismo